# Find the value of b for which f is continuous at all the point on $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x, y) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{sin(x^2+y^2-1)}{x^2+y^2-1} & x^2 + y^2 \neq 1 \\
b & x^2 + y^2 = 1
\end{cases} $. Find the value of b for which f is continuous at all the point on $\mathbb R^2$

Attempt:

Since

$\lim_{x^2+y^2 \to 1} f(x, y) = \lim_{x^2+y^2 - 1 \to 0} \frac{sin(x^2+y^2-1)}{x^2+y^2-1} = 1$

To make f continuous at all points in $\mathbb R^2$, then it needs to be 1?

Would this be right?

Comment: What is $b$ in this question?

Comment: fixed it $$$$$$